# Why is there a need to train the clusterer in Google Earth Engine

Tags: clustering, google-earth-engine, scikit-learn

I'm wondering why before clustering the global `Landsat-7` image in this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/clustering), the authors first trained the clusterer on a subset region around Egypt?

Since the Kmean algorithm is supposed to be unsupervised, I though there was no need to train it beforehand.

The line of code I'm puzzled about is this one:

```js
var clusterer = ee.Clusterer.wekaKMeans(15).train(training);
```

Is the `train()` method above the equivalent of the method `fit()` in [Scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both unsupervised and supervised learning models are *trained* using a set of training data, but the characteristics of the training data differ.

[Unsupervised learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsupervised_learning) models only on require **unlabled** training data. In Earth Engine these models are trained using [ee.Cluster.train()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeclusterertrain), using the `features` and `inputProperties` arguments to specify the unlabeled training data.

[Supervised learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning) models require **labeled** training data. In Earth Engine these models are trained using [ee.Classifier.train()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeclassifiertrain), using the `features`, `classProperty` and `inputProperties` arguments to specify the labeled training data, with the extra `classProperty` indicating the data labels.

Comment: What's the point of the training in the `Unsupervised models`? Can't we just skip it and perform the clustering directly on the larger image in the Google Earth Engine example?

Comment: A separate training step allows you to train a model on a region of an image, and apply the model to the same region, a different region or a different image altogether.